# What is BufferStrategy.show() doing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, bufferedstrategy

In my code, I noticed that I get the same result when I remove the call to the show() method of the BufferStrategy.

I have a function which draws a BufferedImage using the drawImage() method.

```
public void swapBuffers()
{
    //graphics.drawImage(BufferedImage, x, y, w, h, observer)
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 640, 480, null);
    bufferStrategy.show();
}
```

What's confusing me is that when I remove the bufferStrategy.show() method, and change the image being displayed, the program still renders the new image. I thought the purpose of the bufferStrategy.show() method was to display the buffer onto the JFrame? Why do I get the same results when I remove the method?